# What perk challenges are easiest to make "pro"?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops

Of all the perks, which has the easiest challenges for upgrading to "pro"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got [Lightweight Pro](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Lightweight), [Second Chance Pro](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Second_Chance) and [Warlord Pro](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Warlord_(perk)) without even trying, really. And I'm honestly a below average player.

IMO, [Ghost Pro](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Ghost_(perk)) and [Hardened Pro](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Hardened_(perk)) are the hardest to get.

Comment: BONUS: When you prestige, you get to earn them all over again! lol

Comment: I just got the destroy equipment challenge completed, so all I have to get is 15 more downed aircraft and I'll get Ghost Pro.... before I hit prestige :-(  Thanks.

Comment: Well Ghost pro isn't that hard to get. Taking down spy planes counts as well. And as for the sentry gun, that's just one sentry gun to take out. I got Ghost pro without even realizing it because of my habit of taking out spy planes to rank up faster.

Comment: The hardest part of Ghost Pro was FINDING a Sentry Gun. lol. The rest is pretty easy.  They're all pretty easy, really.

Comment: nah, the hardest is `Flak Jacket Pro`. Most of the time when you try to toss back the grenade it explodes in your hand :S

Answer (score 1):

This would be subjective depending on the players skill level and the type of game modes they like to play.

However, assuming the pro perks on the wii are the same as those on the other platforms, some of the easier perks would be:

- [Ghost Pro](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Ghost_(perk)) assuming you can find a sentry gun to destroy.
- [Hardened Pro](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Hardened)
- [Hacker Pro](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Hacker), which compliments hardened

These seem easier to me because the challenge requirements can be meet through common game play scenarios.

Comment: Ghost Pro is pretty hard, actually, only because of that Sentry Gun kill you need. It's not hard to kill one, I got mine by picking one off from far away, but it's hard to actually find one to begin with.

Comment: That said, you see a lot of Sentry Guns in Domination and/or other objective based game types involving defending a position.

Comment: I usually run sentry gun when trying to get Ghost pro and then chunk it at the enemy's position. That way I'm sure they will have a sentry when I need one.

Comment: I got lucky and found a sentry gun, but I haven't hit prestige so I'll have to do it again :-(

Answer (score 0):

I generally earn Second Chance Pro by level 15 or so, but this one is only easy if you're good at realizing where you were shot from and snap-aiming quickly. As FishOfPrey mentioned, it will really depend on how you play.

I also recommend Hardline Pro for earning quickly. One of your perks to Spy Plane or RCXD and earning seven in one round should be super easy. You might even need to intentionally die to keep it going. Sharing care packages is a snap if you play with friends, so the only challenge is a kill-streak of 7 which isn' too hard at all.

I generally also do Warlord or Sleight of Hand, but they are a touch harder.

Comment: I naturally have to reload so I got Sleight of Hand pretty easily with an SMG :-)  Thanks.